# Detect exact position of a word or number in a sentence with machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, tensorflow

I'm trying to come up with an ML model/s to detect if a sentence has sensitive data(telephone number, IBAN, address, etc.) and also get the position of said sensitive data.

For Example "My name is Peter and my telephone number is 0123456789. Have a nice day."

The End result should look like this: "My name is Peter and my telephone number is XXXXXXXXXXX. Have a nice day."

My first idea was to split this into different models.
First I have a model which detects if a sentence contains a telephone number or IBAN or both. Then I want another model which can find me the specific position so I can redact the target with no other information loss.
I managed to get the first model somewhat working with okay results but I'm out of ideas for the second one.

At the moment I mainly use TensorFlow/sci-kit.

Comment: Why are you approaching this as an ML model as opposed to a regex?